# How do I check the memory used by an activeX control in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

There is an aspx page which uses the  *OWC Spread Sheet* Active X control which loads an excel sheet,  but sometimes the browser becomes busy/slow.

I would like to see the stats of this ActiveX control like memory used, CPU load... etc

I tried using Process Explorer and NTSD but could not trace it.

Can anybody give me a hand please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps as you're asking about IE, but you might want to take a look at Google Chrome. In Chrome, ActiveXs run as a separate process. Using the browser's build-in task manager you can see exactly how much memory the ActiveX is consuming (as well as how much CPU and networking).

As for IE, you can try creating a version of the web page that does not include the ActiveX, and see how much memory IE uses. Then, load the original page that does contain the ActiveX, and see the difference in memory consumption. It will not be accurate, but it could give you the hint you need.

Answer (score 0):

As ActiveX controls generally (and in this case always) run in-process, there's no way to directly tell how much memory a given control is using.  You have to run side-by-side experiments.  You probably *could* try to track allocations and frees using a profiler, but this would be a painstaking process to put it mildly.